# Diablo III, Why people always do the same in Adventure mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've played around 70 times on **Adventure** mode (in **Normal** difficulty, and played other modes) and people always do the same, no matter the difficulty mode (unless **Tormento**), they just does the bountys of **Tristam** and after that all the people leaves from game (maybe to join again other party to repeat the same procedure), I've seen people with +300 paragon levels doing this all the time, seems not reasonable to me 'cause they could be playing on **Tormento** mode to drop more and gain more exp, exist a reasonable reason to determine this behavior of almost all the players?

Of course sometimes (very rare sometimes) a group can do other bounties of other maps but from my experience is very strange to see it.

I don't judge other players, I just would like to know whether maybe I'm missing something important about why people does this... is only to be the easiest mode to gain the reward from **Tyriel** NPC or what? really is distasteful for me 'cause I never can do other bounties, all people leaves always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why people do the bounties in act 1 normal is the so called "split farming act 1". Split farming is the term for everyone going to a different bounty and completeing it. People who do this want to get as much Rift Keystones as possible to be able to farm nephalem rifts endlessly.

Another reason is that in act 1 bounty rewards there is the [most wanted ring](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/ring-of-royal-grandeur-3qRFop) in the whole game. This ring can only be found in act 1 rewards, so people can specifically farm for it.

Comment: but in any of the bounties of the Act 1 (in normal mode) I've not droped the keystones, I only saw them on Tormento mode so I suppose that can't be droped in normal mode in Act 1 (please correct me if I think wrong) but very high level people still playing that act1 in normal mode just to do only the Act 1 run. thanks for answer

Comment: rift keystones also "drop" in normal. You won't see them drop as they come directly into your inventory. additionally you get 2 rift keystones from the tyrael reward.

Comment: `additionally you get 2 rift keystones from the tyrael reward` you mean 'sometimes with luck you can get 2 keystones...' or 'always you get 2 keystones...' 'cause like I've said I've played around 70 times in adventure normal mode and Tyriel never gave me keystones, only the reward box that drops items. PS: I have collected only 2 keystones in the whole played time.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Each Bounty in an act, **except first one**, awards you with a Rift Keystone Fragment. Two fragments then drop from Tyrael's bounty bag. If this is not what happens in your game, you are playing not the same Diablo 3 everyone else is playing. Or you are not telling the truth :-(

Comment: Yeah the number one reason is to just farm split bounties on normal act 1 for the ring.